# PHP Dynamic table with content grouping

Tags: php

### What I am trying to do

I have an array which looks like this -

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 23-09-2015
        [name] => Public Transport
        [group_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [date] => 23-09-2015
        [name] => Parking
        [group_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [date] => 23-09-2015
        [name] => Food
        [group_id] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [date] => 23-09-2015
        [name] => Fix
        [group_id] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [date] => 23-09-2015
        [name] => Entertainment
        [group_id] => 3
    )

)
```

I want to list it in table with grouping done according to the group id

The group has Transportation [1], Accommodation [2] and Allowance [3]. [4] is ungrouped.

The table structure need to look as shown below.

```
  ID| Date     | Name             |
  ---------------------------------
  ---------------------------------
  1 |23-09-2015|Public Transport
  2 |23-09-2015|Parking
  ---------------------------------
          TRANSPORTATION
  ---------------------------------
  3 |23-09-2015|Food
  ---------------------------------
          ACCOMMODATION
  ---------------------------------
  4 |23-09-2015|Fix
  ---------------------------------
          ALLOWANCE
  ---------------------------------
  5 |23-09-2015|Entertainment
```

As you can see here id 1 & 2 comes under Transportation, 3 comes under accommodation, 4 comes under allowance and entertainment does not have group.
If any group dosenot have data in the array then it should show NO DATA AVAILABLE

```
  ---------------------------------
  3 |23-09-2015|Food
  ---------------------------------
          ACCOMMODATION
  ---------------------------------
       No data available
  ---------------------------------
          ALLOWANCE
  ---------------------------------
```

### What I tried

```
     <?php
     $j = 1;
     foreach ($summary as $list) {
        if ($j != $list['group_id']) {

             if ($j == 1) {
                   $group = 'Transportation';
             } else if ($j == 2) {
                    $group = 'Accomodation';
              } else if ($j == 3) {
                    $group = 'Allowances';
              } else {
                    $group = '';
              }
          ?>

                        <tr class="summary-title">
                            <td colspan="7"><?php echo $group; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
      <tr>

           <td><?php echo $list['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $list['date']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $list['name']; ?></td>
      </tr>
        <?php
            $j = $list['group_id'];
        }
        ?>
```

The array is ordered according with group_id as ascending. Group id will have values 1, 2, 3, 4 always.

### Problem with my code

It works partially. But I am unable to show NO DATA AVAILABLE when there's no value in array with the group_id. Also if group_id = 4 is not available in array then it doesnot set ALLOWANCE at the bottom as the array loop finishes before the value is set.

Comment: sorry for the long post

Comment: What output do you expect? As I understood,  groups: Transportation, Accommodation etc. storing in table **group**, is it right?

Comment: I want the table to be displayed in the above shown format. The grouping is done using group_id. If a group_id doesn't exist then it will show No data found under that group

Comment: So, In row with name **Entertainment** group_id is **null** or **3**?

Comment: Row with name Entertainment group_id is 4. 4 actually marks data coming under no group

Comment: It is will be very interesting when groups will near 200))) What then? Or for example, on next week need to add new group. You will be rewrite **if else** condition?) Or for example, in db change id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Removed the whole page because its getting to chaotic right now.

```
$summary = array();
$summary[] = array('id'=>1, 'date'=>"23-09-2915", 'name'=>"Public transpor1", 'group_id'=> 1);
$summary[] = array('id'=>2, 'date'=>"24-09-2915", 'name'=>"Public transpor2", 'group_id'=> 3);
$summary[] = array('id'=>3, 'date'=>"25-09-2915", 'name'=>"Public transpor3", 'group_id'=> 1);
$summary[] = array('id'=>4, 'date'=>"26-09-2915", 'name'=>"Public transpor4", 'group_id'=> 2);
$summary[] = array('id'=>5, 'date'=>"27-09-2915", 'name'=>"Public transpor5", 'group_id'=> 1);
$newarray = array('Transportation'=>array(),'Accomodation'=>array(),'Allowances'=>array(),'Not found'=>array());
foreach ($summary as $list) {
    if(isset($list['group_id'])){
         $testid = $list['group_id'];
    }else{
         $testid = 4;
    }
    if ($testid  == 1) {
        $group = 'Transportation';
    } else if ($testid  == 2) {
        $group = 'Accomodation';
    } else if ($testid  == 3) {
        $group = 'Allowances';
    } else {
        $group = 'Not found';
    }
    $newarray[$group][] = $list;
}
echo "<table>";
foreach($newarray as $key => $array){
    echo "<tr><th>".$key."</th></tr>";
    if(count($array) > 0){
        foreach($array as $row){
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td>Not data</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

This should do what you want now but seriously, put some effort into it lol. I'm not going to continue to edit it until it does what you want if you're so unclear with your questions

Comment: content is repeating. All rows are shown under every group

Comment: sorry little typo. Got it. But still what to do when there's a group_id not available in $summary. Then I still want to show the group with content 'NO DATA FOUND' as shown above

Comment: @Developer Simply use isset to see if group_id exists in the array. I edited my answer

Comment: Its not working. I need no data found to be shown in content area not group header area. If group_id = 2 is not there in array. Then I want to show not data found in content area and below that header Accommodation.

Comment: I think better name of groups store in db, but not hardcoding like **$group = 'Transportation'; etc...**.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you. Here a small example.

Dump:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `my`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `FK_category_category_group` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_category_category_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `category_group` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`, `group_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'Public Transport', 1),
    (2, 'Parking', 1),
    (3, 'Food', 2),
    (4, 'Fix', 3),
    (5, 'Entertainment', 3),
    (6, 'Category without group 1', NULL),
    (7, 'Category without group 2', NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category` ENABLE KEYS */;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category_group` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `category_group` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (2, 'Accommodation '),
    (3, 'Allowance '),
    (1, 'TRANSPORTATION');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `category_group` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

PHP:

```
$categoriesByGroups = array();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my', 'root');
$query = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT c.id AS category_id,
           c.name AS category_name,
           c.group_id,
           g.name AS group_name
      FROM category AS c
      LEFT JOIN category_group AS g ON g.id = c.group_id
');

$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['group_id'] != null) {
        $groupId = $row['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = 0;
    }

    if (!isset($categoriesByGroups[$groupId])) {
        $categoriesByGroups[$groupId] = array(
            'categories' => array(),
            'group' => $groupId == null ? 'Without group' : $row['group_name']
        );
    }

    $categoriesByGroups[$groupId]['categories'][] = $row['category_name'];
}

foreach ($categoriesByGroups as $group) {
    echo 'Group: ' . $group['group'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Categories: <br/>';
    foreach ($group['categories'] as $category) {
        echo $category . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '--------------------------------<br/>';
}
```